# passing a string into a function

Tags: c, string, io

I am trying to pass a string into a function in C. That string will entered by the user and then passed on to the function to write to a text file. Iknow this seems very basic but I am just learning C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void read() {

        char text[50][30],buffer[150];

        int i=0;
        FILE *file_in;
        file_in=fopen("test.txt","r");

        if (file_in == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file\n");
        }

        while (fgets(buffer,150,file_in)) {
                strcpy(text[i],buffer);
                printf("line %d: %s\n",i,text[i]);
                i++;
        }

        getchar();

        fclose(file_in);
}

void write(char str[])
{
        FILE *file_in;
        file_in=fopen("test.txt","a");

        if (file_in == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file\n");
        }

        //write to the file
        fprintf(file_in, "\n%s", str);
//      fputs(str, file_in);

        fclose(file_in);
}

int main()
{
        read();

        char msg[50];

        printf("Enter some text: ");
        puts(msg);

        write(msg); 

        return 0;
}
```

It writes to the file, but it writes weird characters, not what I actually type. What amI doing wrong?

Comment: What DOES it write? Something like 0x049569...?

Comment: I writes something like a box with many characters in it.

Comment: Please post what it prints in your question

Comment: You never store a value in `msg`, so it contains garbage.

Comment: I tried to paste the output here but when I paste it it doesn't actually show up on here. When I look at the fileon the vim editor it shows up as ^A. When I open it on gedt it shows up as garbage

Comment: Not really important but if you're not modifying the data pointed to by `str` it is good practice to change `char str[]` to `const char str[]`.

Comment: `puts(msg);` --> `fgets(msg, 50, stdin);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int read() {

        char text[50][30],buffer[150];

        int i=0;
        FILE *file_in;
        file_in=fopen("test.txt","r");

        if (file_in == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file\n");
        }

        while (fgets(buffer,150,file_in)) {
                strcpy(text[i],buffer);
                printf("line %d: %s\n",i,text[i]);
                i++;
        }

       // getchar();why you were using this?

        fclose(file_in);
      //  return 0;
}

void write(char str[])
{
        FILE *file_in;
        file_in=fopen("test.txt","a");

        if (file_in == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file\n");
        }

        //write to the file
        fprintf(file_in, "\n%s", str);
//      fputs(str, file_in);

        fclose(file_in);
}

int main()
{
        char msg[50];
        read();



        printf("Enter some text: ");
       // getchar();
        gets(msg);//It reads in msg 

        write(msg); 

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome..I did not provide the changes. You should go through others answers and donot use gets use fgets instead.

Comment: The down voter of this answer should _really leave a reason_.  i.e. poster is fairly new to SO, give him an idea of how to improve the answer.

Comment: @jahan - regarding your comment _// getchar();why you were using this?_.  In a console app, `getchar()` is a good way to pause execution so you can see the output of a `printf()` before execution collapses the console.

Comment: @ryyker thanks for telling me that. You know some people are addicted to down vote here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've confused `gets` with `puts`. `puts` writes a string to the console. `gets` reads a string from the console. Switch them out and your program should work.

Microsoft's compiler often warns against insecure or deprecated functions, like `gets`. You may use `fgets` instead, as it doesn't allow buffer overflows.

Here's an example:

```
fgets(msg, 50, stdin);
```

or

```
fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
```

Comment: did you just advise someone to use `gets` ?

Comment: I tired it using gets.It worked but it says it was deprecated. Is there a better way?

Comment: @TaylorFlores: Not for text input. `fread` will read a specified number of bytes, which means it won't stop at the end of a line (when you type Enter). Use `fgets`.

Comment: @flaco I changed my suggestion to `fgets`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't call your functions `read()` and `write()` — pick something more specific. The function names `read()` and `write()` are already used by the system for low-level file operations, and trying to define them yourself will cause unexpected behavior.

Second: you are never initializing the contents of the `msg` variable or reading any data into it, so its contents will be random. (Remember that `puts()` prints data; it doesn't read anything.)

Answer (score 0):

When you write `char msg[50];`, it contains indeterminate values. It's not zero-initialized or anything.

The `puts(msg);` line writes this garbage out, and then `write(msg);` writes that garbage to a file.

I guess you intended to have some code for inputting text, after the `printf` and before the `puts`.

NB. In your `read()` function (which you don't call yet), you should make the `fgets` buffer size match the width of your array , and you should check you don't run off the end of your array if the file has many lines.

Also it would be wise to name your functions something other than `read` and `write`, because in a POSIX environment there are already functions by that name which may clash.